# Lua: How to find out if an element is a table instead of a string/number?

Tags: lua, lua-table

As the title says, what function or check can I do to find out if a lua element is a table or not?

```
local elem = {['1'] = test, ['2'] = testtwo}
if (elem is table?) // <== should return true
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
print(type(elem)) -->table
```

the type function in Lua returns what datatype it's first parameter is (string)

Comment: That's slow for me is there any other method ?

Answer (score 34):

In the context of the original question,

```
local elem = {['1'] = test, ['2'] = testtwo}
if (type(elem) == "table") then
  -- do stuff
else
  -- do other stuff instead
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

You may find this helps readability:

```
local function istable(t) return type(t) == 'table' end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `type()`:

```
local elem = {1,2,3}
print(type(elem) == "table")
-- true
```